# adding multiple buttons in a popup window

Tags: python, popup, kivy

I created a popup window. Usually we use pop.dismiss to close the popup. But I want to add some buttons in that popup. I have 4 buttons. When 2 of these buttons are pressed they should show another widget(boxlayout). **But when I touch these buttons the app crashes.**

However, other 2 of these 4 buttons, when touched they show another popup window. It works well without crashing.

1. from popup window>button touch>showing another popup window > no crashing
2. from popup>button any of these 4 buttons> in order to showing boxlayout widget> app crashed!

Can anyone please explain this? How should I fix this?

**(.py) file**

```py
    class abc(Popup):   

        def about_app(self):
            self.clear_widgets()
            self.add_widget(about())    

        def about_leo(self):
            self.clear_widgets()
            self.add_widget(page1())

        def help(self):
            pops=help_popup()
            pops.open() 

        def website(self):
            pops=website()
            pops.open()
```

**(.kv) file**

```
<abc>:  
    title: 'LEO CLUB'
    title_color: 1, 0, 0, 1 
    title_size: 50
    title_align:'center'
    background: 'popup.png'
    size_hint: .6, 0.8
    pos_hint: {'right': .6, 'top': 1}

    BoxLayout:          
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'                      

            Button:
                bold: True
                text: "About LEO"
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                on_release: root.about_leo()
            Button:
                bold:True
                text: "About App"
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                on_release: root.about_app()                                                 
            Button:
                bold: True
                text: "Website"
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                on_release: root.website()
            Button:
                bold: True
                text: "Help"
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                on_release: root.help()
```

​

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: are you asking about adding my code?

Comment: i did it. now please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is calling `self.add_widget()` in the `abc` class (which is a `Popup`), but a `Popup` can only have one child (it's `content`). The call to `clear_widgets()` removes all the children of the `Popup`, but does not change the `content` property (it probably should). So even though you have removed the `children` of the `Popup`, it still thinks it has a non-empty `content`. So, what you really need to do is just set the new `content`. In your `abc` class, just replace those two methods with:

```
def about_app(self):
    self.content = about()

def about_leo(self):
    self.content = page1()
```

Comment: really its working a little bit better than earlier. but,  by calling self.content=page1(), its just showing the page1 inside that popup window. its not clearing the base window below the popup which is still visible due to transparency and the popup window's size is (.5,.5). so, when i call the page1() then its showing page1 in that popup having about (0.5,0.5) size. after that if my page1 has a button to redirect to another page, and when i touch that button of page1, then it shows that another window again in that popup without clearing that visible transparent window below.

Comment: That's why we ask for a [mcve]. There must be something else (not in your post) that is affecting the transparency of the `Popup`. Some possibilities are if you are setting the `opacity` property of the `Popup` or that the `popup.png` has some transparency. The default `Popup` is not transparent.

Comment: hello, john, I did solve my problem by doing so many research on internet and by my hard work. thank you for your kind help